# Does toggling in React affect highchart display?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am just toggling a show value on click of a button as follow:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome </h1>
        </header>

        <div id={'container'}>
          <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            options={this.state.options}
          />
        </div>

        <button onClick={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)}>More info</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

ToggleHidden and constructor are defined as follows:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={isHidden:true,options:{},currentdisplay:{}};
    //this.show= this.show.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.callApi()
    .then(res => this.setState({options:res}))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({
        isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    })
}
```

For some reason, my chart gets pushed up when I click the button for the first time and then on every consecutive click it remains the same. I am not able to understand this behaviour. 
The options for my chart are set by calls to a backend express server. The code is as follows:

```
callApi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/api/xdata', {
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  });

  const body = await response.json();
  const response2 = await fetch('/api/ydata', {
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  });
  const body2 = await response2.json();

  const re = JSON.parse(body);

  var re2 = JSON.parse(re2);

  var options = {
    title: {
      text: 'Trying'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: { text: 'xdata' },
      categories: re.xdata
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'y data'
      }
    },
    series: {
      data: re2.ydata.map(Number)
    }
  };

  if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
  return options;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

React `setState` causes `chart.update`, you can check it in this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/50p5l109nn

To avoid updating the chart, add small modification to `HighchartsReact` wrapper:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function() {
  if (this.props.update) {
    this.chart.update(
      Object.assign({}, this.props.options),
      true,
      !(this.props.oneToOne === false)
    );
  }
},
```

And set `update` props to false:

```
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      constructorType={"chart"}
      options={options}
      update={false}
    />
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/5256qj19lx

Comment: Hi. Could you please have a look to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879308/highchartsreact-does-not-render-properly-in-custom-tabs