# HighchartsReact does not render properly in custom Tabs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm using [HighchartsReact](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) and I'm struggling to render my charts properly inside a simple tab implementation. Every time I change tabs, the charts get "stuck" on the previous rendering and never refresh.
[Here is the sample code](https://codepen.io/jose-nunez/pen/bOgBOY). Thanks!

```
const chart1 = {
  "title": { "text": "Chart 1" },
  xAxis: { type:'datetime' },
  "series": [
    { "name": "ONe line", "data": randData1 },
    { "name": "Another LIne", "data": randData2 }
  ],
  chart: { events: { load: function(){} } }
}

const chart2 = {
  "title": { "text": "Chart 2" },
  "series": [
    { "name": "First Line", "data": randData3 },
    { "name": "Second Line", "data": randData4 }
  ],
  chart: { events: { load: function(){} } }
}


const TheChart = ({ chartData }) => <HighchartsReact highcharts = { Highcharts } options = { chartData } />

const tabHeaders = [
  'Chart One', 
  'Chart Two'
];
const tabContent = [
  <TheChart chartData={ chart1 } />,
  <TheChart chartData={ chart2 } />
 ];

const tabsProps = { tabHeaders, tabContent };
ReactDOM.render(<Tabs { ...tabsProps } />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/18836vk8oj - React does not switch components from the same class, the first component is only updated. Creating a new class for the second component is one of the ways to solve the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmqvmX?editors=0010

```
const tabContent = [
  <div>...</div>,
  <TheChart chartData={ chart1 } />,
  <TheChart2 chartData={ chart2 } />
];
```

Updating component with a chart fires `chart.update()`, so for example if you want to change `xAxis.type` you must change it in two configurations:

```
chart.update({
    series [...],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    }
});

chart.update({
    series [...],
    xAxis: {
        type: 'linear'
    }
});
```

Another issue here is that Highcharts for performance mutate series config object: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9732 - so you need create a deep copy of your options or change the structure of the project.

Live demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdZmMO?editors=0010

Comment: I had a look. I'll use the "new class" approach, as my config objects come with references to functions, thus, any JSON.stringify will remove them from the new copy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, things get more confusing if I implement both situations together. I'll avoid this in my project, of course. https://codepen.io/jose-nunez/pen/ZVKGEe?editors=0010

Comment: Hi Jose, All this is related to the problems I described above. If you add `linear` axis type, everything seems to work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVKPWR?editors=0010. You can notice the animation caused by `chart.update` by switching the third and fourth chart.